# how much time does it take to slackbuild the chromium package?

Tags: linux, slackware

I am new to the Slackware and I was trying to install chromium browser. I found out that i can download the slackbuild and source file from the slackbuild.org and can build and install it. So, I did the same. what i did was

- Downloaded both the files.(chromium.tar.gz and chromium-31.0.1650.57.tar.gz)
- Untarred the chromium.tar.gz file.
- copied the chromium-31.0.1650.57.tar.gz file to the directory created after untaring the     chromium.tar.gz file
- launched the command ./chromium.SlackBuild chromium-31.0.1650.57.tar.gz.

Now the problem is, it's been compiling for last six hours. I am pretty much confused about what's going on. I couldn't cancel it because i thought let me wait for few more minutes and in doing so i have spent six hours.  I don't think it's normal.Is it??

Anybody have any idea of where did i go wrong?? Please i want help.
Edit : It took time but I got it install. Still It'll be helpful if someone could tell me why did it take so long ? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Because chromium including webkit and v8 is a huge project. This is also stated in the chromium developer wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromium takes ages to build because it is a complex piece of software. I would advise to use Alien Bob's packages, since they are kept up-to-date and ready to install. Check out http://alien.slackbook.org/blog/tag/chromium/.